# Add MouseListener for just inside the JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, mouseevent, mouselistener

I am trying to implement a mouse listener to my Java Applet game. I tried everything from adding the listener these ways:
- frame.addMouseListener(this);
- addMouseListener(this); //I implement it in my class heading

My intentions are simple. I have java rectangles, and I want to do specific actions
when the mouse enters or clicks within the rectangle. I know how to get the X and Y positions of the mouse and test it against the rectangle but a problem arises. The mouse listeners listen for the whole screen, instead of just within my frame. My frame is 480wide and 800height so I want those coordinates tested. Any resolutions to this?

Comment: Can you show some code? Its not that simple to understand the real problem if there is no code...

Comment: "The mouse listeners listen for the whole screen, instead of just within my frame". Really?

Comment: Also try to add the mouseListener to the panel you want to work on! Or you implement the MouseListener Interface to your whole frame...

Answer (score 0):

> The mouse listeners listen for the whole screen..

No they don't.  The event produced does have the ability to report the point *relative to* the main screen, using [`MouseEvent.getLocationOnScreen()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#getLocationOnScreen%28%29).  It seems you need [`MouseEvent.getPoint()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#getPoint%28%29) instead, which:

> Returns the x,y position of the event *relative to the source component.*